# Capybara/Selenium test for jquery autocomplete not working if Firefox is not made active

Tags: firefox, selenium, capybara

I'm running into an issue with the following code in a capybara test (covering a jquery autocomplete select)

```
page.evaluate_script %Q{ $('.ui-menu-item a:contains("#{target}")').trigger("mouseenter").click(); }
```

When Firefox is made active while the test is running, the test passes.  When it remains inactive the test fails.  This appears to be documented in [this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=157) issue but I am wondering if anyone has found a work around.

I'm on OS X 10.6.7 and have tried FF 4 and 3.6.10

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative way I'm using the [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit) gem instead of selenium together with the [headless](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless) gem and that works great for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on a mac, you can work around this by using applescript to force firefox to the front. Add the following line to your ruby code wherever you need firefox to be on top:

```
`osascript -e \"tell application \\\"Firefox\\\" to activate\"`
```

Taken from here: https://gist.github.com/2427601